# How do I set up a web server for my site that I can send requests to and recieve data from?

Tags: firebase, server, raspberry-pi, firebase-authentication, webserver

Let's say I have an admin page with data that hides on load and shows when the admin logs in. This is insecure as anyone can just inspect it and click 'show'. I would like to set up some sort of server (I'm new to this sort of stuff so don't know what is required) that I can send the attempted username and password and it will return the data if the user is an admin. This way it would be more secure.

**If it helps:** I have a raspberry pi (C) 2011.

Comment: You might be able to do this without your own server, by taking advantage of the database rules. You can simply hide the admin section on page load, but enforce access using rules. If someone discovers the admin ui, they won't be able to read or write data that you haven't given permission for. A true "permissions" system is a bit complicated with Firebase rules, but it's possible.

Comment: Can you give me an example of some rules?

Comment: The Firebase docs have a guide with many examples. [Here's the guide for realtime database rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/). Firestore and Storage have their own rules, also explained in the docs.